# getting stuck as ssh known hosts in chef

Tags: git, deployment, ubuntu-12.04, chef-infra, knife

I am trying to deploy rails app into test server with chef cookbook. I am able to pull the code into test server, but when I am trying to do bundle update through recipe, I am stuck at updating bundles of private repositories. bundle update stops at following.

The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established

wrapper file contains 
" exec ssh  -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no  -i "/home/ubuntu/.ssh/id_rsa" "$@" "

How to overcome this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [ssh_known_hosts](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/ssh_known_hosts) cookbook:

```
ssh_known_host 'github.com'
```

Comment: I am getting a "recipe compile error" when using this with vagrant. http://pastebin.com/4SBU6Z2N. Any idea?